# Anchor links not working in Wordpress - I'm stumped!

Tags: html, anchor

Anchor links! Can't seem to get them to work. I've created anchor links above every timeslot, with the name coming from the post-slug. I have tried using the anchor links, like this:
http://ecodistrictssummit.com/tues-oct-23#fastcash-workshop-with-ioby

And I have tried using div IDs, like this:
http://ecodistrictssummit.com/tues-oct-23#timeslot-1033

Every anchor moves you down the page, but never gets you past the first entry.

Any help would be much appreciated! It's a client's site that is sadly live. :/

Thanks!

Comment: Anchor ID questions are more about HTML than WordPress.  I'll migrate this over to Stack Overflow where it will be on-topic so you can get some help.

Comment: A little HTML would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Alan - My first try (using #timeslot-1033) resulted in what you described.

Then, suspecting a CSS-related issue, I set "Page Style" to "No Style" in Firefox, reloaded the page, and got to the Tuesday 4:00 place. (That's where it SHOULD take me, right? So I think my suspicion was correct.

I'd try stripping some declarations from my style sheet (.timeslot width = 100%?) and such.

HTH.
Jeff Cohan

Comment: Thanks so much, Jeff! It was totally a CSS thing. It seems that when I was using empty <a> tags and the .timeslot divs, they didn't have set dimensions. When I used the program-details div as anchors, which has text inside of it, it worked! Merci!

Comment: You bet, Alan. Glad I saw your question. I had had a similar problem.

Comment: Alan - If my answer helped you solve the problem, it would be nice if you marked it as the chosen answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a slightly different answer that worked well for me. I learned about id tags. So for example, I added an id to a heading tag:

```
<h3 id="game">Game Night</h3>
```

This worked great!